# How to have selectedColor in a colorPicker to be random

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am trying to have a random color to be picked as default for my `ColorPicker`. I am running my script on the creation complete of my Panel.

The script code is given below:

```
public var someColor:String = new String();

    private function init():void{
        var myColor:Number = Math.round( Math.random()*0xFFFFFF );
        someColor = "0x"+myColor.toString(16);      
    }
```

and the code for the ColorPicker is:

```
<mx:ColorPicker id="calendar_color" width="20" height="20" selectedColor="{someColor}"/>
```

Even though, when I see the color in the var someColor, it shows a random color every time, but the colorPicker is not displaying the color.

Please let me know, what am I doing wrong here. And how it can be fixed.

Comment: possible timing issue? try using addedToStage event to call init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `[Bindable]` metadata:

```
[Bindable]
public var someColor:String = new String();
```

Comment: @Zeeshan Rang, Is there a reason why you even need to bind?  Couldn't you just do `calendar_color.selectedColor = yourColor`?

Answer (score 2):

1) Why do you have `someColor` as `String`? Therefore you've got two unnececcary type conversions: from `Number` to `String` (`myColor.toString(16)`) and from `String` to `uint` (`selectedColor="{someColor}"`). Why not just write this:

```
[Bindable] public var someColor:uint = 0;

private function init():void{
    someColor = Math.random()*0xFFFFFF; 
}
```

2) And one more thing I also don't like - in current answer you've got actually uneccecary binding, the one that will only shoot once, and you should not forget to call `init()` somewhere in youre code. I'd better change it on function call:

```
private function getRandomColor():uint{
    return Math.random()*0xFFFFFF;
}

<mx:ColorPicker id="calendar_color" width="20" height="20"
    selectedColor="{getRandomColor()}"/>
```

Here `getRandomColor()` will be automatically called on `ColorPicker` initialization. One unavoidable type conversion (from `Number` to `uint`), no bindings, no useless property, shorter code.

That's not premature optimization, that's removing premature pessimization.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from this post but what class is

```
    public var someColor:String = new String();
```

in. you will just want to verify that it can be reached through the reference you made.